# What did `uniq -t` do?

Tags: uniq

I have some old code from 2003 which uses `-t` option for `uniq` command. It throws an error since that option is probably not supported anymore.

Here's the piece which uses the command:

```
egrep -n "{ IA32_OP" ia32-decode.c | \
    awk '{ print $1 $3 $4 }' | \
    sort -t '(' +1 | \
    uniq -t ':' -f 1 | \
    sed 's/\(.*\)\:IA32_OP(\(.*\)),/#define IA32_OP_\2 \1/g' >> ia32_opcodes.h
```

What did that option do back then? What can I substitute that command with?

Comment: Here's the source BTW: https://web.archive.org/web/20040217131820/http://www.team-teso.net/projects/objobf/objobf-0.5.0.tar.bz2

Comment: According to [`man uniq`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq), `-f 1` avoids comparing the first field. I'd infer from `-t ':'` that `-t` is supposed to change the field seperator from blanks to `:`.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546337/uniq-command-how-to-get-delimiter-option-and-search-on-the-basis-of-column Maybe `-t` was a Debian-specific option that was later removed?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=117016

Comment: I always wondered why `uniq` didn't have the same `-t` and `-k` as sort or why sort didn't have all the features of `uniq` incorporated (since it now has `-u`). Those `-w`/`-f`/`-s` from GNU uniq don't make sense. Why couldn't they use the same syntax as `sort`.

Comment: The [Debian changelog](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/c/coreutils/coreutils_8.13-3.5_changelog) records the loss of this feature under the heading "Remove some ancient debian-specific patches" in version 5.93-1

Comment: See http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=31106 which was fixed by adding that `-t` in textutils 2.0-3 in Debian woody

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only reference I could find to `-t` is in [this patch](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-textutils/2002-07/msg00026.html) on a GNU mailing list, which contains among other clues, this:

```
+  -t, --separator=S     use a character in string S as field separator\n\
```

This apparently was a GNU extension but no longer in use. It appears to allow selecting a delimiting character for fields other than spaces or tabs.  Try replacing

```
uniq -t ':' -f 1 | \
```

with

```
sed 's/:/ /' | \
uniq -f 1 | \
```

which will replace `:` with spaces which uniq recognizes the field separator.

Comment: I would drop the `g` from `sed`, since only the first field is skipped. At least one colon is needed for the last line to work (hopefully not the first). Still no guarantee it will work though (any of the first fields may contain whitespace)

Comment: @Graeme Good point, edited.

Comment: In Debian, coreutils 5.2.1 indeed had such a patch applied, and apparently it was removed in 5.93-1, that is, in November 2005.

Answer (score 4):

Given the `man` entry for the `-f` option:

> -f, --skip-fields=N
>
> ```
>          avoid comparing the first N fields
> ```

I think it is fairly safe to assume that `-t` specifies the field separator (this is also the case for `sort` in the line above). The combination of the two options would make `uniq` only operate on the part of the line following the first colon.